# OData 4 AspNet: GET by parameter not working

Tags: c#, odata

I'm in the process of converting a web service to use OData.
I've created an ODataController implementation as below:

```
public class PersonController : ODataController
{

    public PersonController()
    {

    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new Person());
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return Ok(new Person());
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }
}
```

And registered the model like so:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person");

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
routeName: "odata",
routePrefix: "odata",
model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

The web app deploys without problems, and the first function works when I call:

```
http://localhost:9200/odata/Customer
 ->
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:9200/odata/$metadata#Person/$entity","Name":"John"
}
```

However, calling http://localhost:9200/odata/Customer(1) fails, the trace on the server log shows that the route is not found:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=404 (NotFound), Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:9200/odata/Person(1), Message='Content-type='application/xml; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
```

I've tried different attribute permutations using ODataRoutePrefix, ODataRoute, EnableQuery on the method, and so far nothing I do seems to help. Tutorials I have seen say that this should work, so now I'm stuck wondering how I'm supposed to get this working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem.

The problem was, the Key defined within the entity was of type String.
This meant that key extracted by FromODataUri had to also be of type String!

In this example, the problem could be fixed by changing key to String type, or by changing the Person key to int type.